# RSpec bisect runs indefinetly

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

This problem is not the same of this: [rspec Bisect Runs Indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598322/rspec-bisect-runs-indefinitely)

My test suite takes ± 10 min to run.
When I run `bundle exec rspec --bisect=verbose`, it gets stuck for more than 1 hour (this was the longest I've waited) in this:

```
bundle exec rspec --bisect=verbose
AssetSync: using /home/belasis/dev/deploy_webapp/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
Bisect started using options: "" and bisect runner: :fork
Running suite to find failures...
```

After I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>, this message appears:

```
Bisect aborted!

The most minimal reproduction command discovered so far is:
  (Not yet enough information to provide any repro command)
```

So, the problem is that it is running nothing and gives no error message. How is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rspec Bisect Runs Indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598322/rspec-bisect-runs-indefinitely)

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and I resolved it with 3 actions. I think it's the last one which helped but others might be important in some cases too:

1. Updated `rspec-core` to 3.9.1 version
2. Ran the bisect with `DISABLE_SPRING=true` env variable
3. Used `shell` bisect_runner instead of the default `fork` one

The last change is achieved by creating a local file with configuration like this:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.bisect_runner = :shell
end
```

Let's call this fine `rsp_shell.rb` and save it in the project root.

And then you have to run bisect like these:

```
bundle exec rspec --require './rsp_shell' --bisect=verbose ...other arguments...
```

Also it looks like it is important to put the require argument before the bisect argument in the command.

The indication that this last setting applied would be the following string in the output of rspec:

```
and bisect runner: :shell
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this from time to time, and the only workaround that sometimes works is trying different RSpec version.

Try downgrading/upgrading it (should be easy if you use bunlder) and try until it works or you loose hope.

But if you find a better workaround or even a real solution please do share it :)

Answer (score 0):

That was a bug, and it has been [recently fixed](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/pull/2669). It's not released yet, so you'll have to use `master` branch.